# Setting XFCE terminal PS1 value and making it permanent

Tags: linux, xfce

I'm trying to add the value PS1='\u@\h: \w\$ ' to my terminal in XFCE. I added the line to (what I think is) the correct area in /etc/profile. The relevant segment is:

```
# Set a default shell prompt:
#PS1='`hostname`:`pwd`# '
PS1='\u@\h: \w\$ '
if [ "$SHELL" = "/bin/pdksh" ]; then
# PS1='! $ '
  PS1='\u@\h: \w\$ '
elif [ "$SHELL" = "/bin/ksh" ]; then
# PS1='! ${PWD/#$HOME/~}$ '
  PS1='\u@\h: \w\$ '
elif [ "$SHELL" = "/bin/zsh" ]; then
# PS1='%n@%m:%~%# '
  PS1='\u@\h: \w\$ '
elif [ "$SHELL" = "/bin/ash" ]; then
# PS1='$ '
  PS1='\u@\h: \w\$ '
else
 PS1='\u@\h: \w\$ '
fi
```

Most of that was already there, I just commented out the existing value and added the one I want.

By manually opening the terminal and doing . profile, I can load these values, but they don't stick - I close the terminal and reopen, and I'm back to sh-4.1$.

Maybe I'm doing this in the wrong place, but how can I make that value stick?

All the info I've found on google is Fedora/Ubuntu-specific. I use Slackware. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about XFCE or your terminal; it's about your shell.

I'm guessing your login shell is `/bin/bash`.  Bash reads several files on startup, depending on whether it's interactive, whether it's a login shell, and probably some other things.  See [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) for the gory details.

For starters, check `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Note that changing `/etc/profile` affects all users on the system.  If you're the only user, it probably doesn't matter, but it's probably still better to make personal customizations in your own home directory.

Comment: .bashrc for me by default.